# How to Create SharePoint Site Directory Web Part in MOSS 2007

Tags: database, sharepoint, web-parts

I want to Create SharePoint Site Directory WebPart which contains links to all the sites created by using Microsoft Office SharePoint Services 2007.

Thanks in Advance,
Shyam

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display to a user all sites in the Site collection that exist, even if that user doesn't have any permissions to view the site?  Or do you only want to show sites that they are allowed to visit?

If the former, you'll need to create your own custom webpart and use RunWithElevatedPrivileges to get the list of all sites and display them.

If the latter, you might be able to use one of these out of the box webparts, depending on your needs:  Memberships, My Sharepoint Sites, Sites In Category, Top Sites